# Change flat data to horizontal with a first column relationship

Tags: excel, vba

Does anyone know of a way to get Excel to do what is shown in the below example

```
A         |     B
================================
Apple     |     Pie
Apple     |     Sauce
Apple     |     Juice
Banana    |     Smoothie
Banana    |     Split
```

into this structure?

```
A        |    B         |     C      |    D      | 
==================================================
Apple    |   Pie        |    Sauce   |   Juice   |
Banana   |   Smoothie   |    Split   |           |
```

I have been searching online and can't find a supported way so far, I want to know if there is a supported way first before I try writing some VBA code to do it.

The usual paste special > transpose does not give this format, because it is not supposed to.

I obviously want to automate this for a large dataset.

Comment: This is not transposition, which is why `paste special | transpose` doesn't give you the results you expect. You may be able to do this with pivot tables & some formulas, but I'd probably just use VBA.

Comment: @DavidZemens Transpose just means to transform into a different context, so I couldnt think of a better word. I know it isn't the same as the paste special > transpose option though.

Comment: In maths, transposition is: interchanging the rows and columns of a given matrix/array.  That's what the `Transpose` option does. You're trying flatten a table and derive unique rows data from repeated rows in column A, you need to flatten it.  Not picking nits on the choice of words, just clarifying as to why the method you tried does not yield the results you desire :)

Comment: I agree with :@David on Pivot + Formulas @Pricey: If you data has some kind if consistency then you can achieve what you want using formulas.

Comment: @DavidZemens I said I couldn't think of a better word to describe what I was doing in my question, I wasn't nit picking. It was an English description not a mathematical one that I was using that is all, I gave an example because I knew it would only cause issues like your comment.

Comment: Yes, I understand that -- which is why I said that **I'm not nitpicking** but rather, just trying to help clarify your request and shed some light on why "the usual paste special > transpose" doesn't work.  When you then try to argue that you didn't mean "transpose" when you said "transpose", that's when I had to point you to the maths definition -- again, simply to clarify. While this may not have helped **you** it may help the next person with a similar question who stumbles upon this thread. Cheers.

Comment: @DavidZemens Sorry I read that line as "Not picking nits" instead of "I'm not picking nits" so my mistake. Its understandable that your comment will help the next person, that is why I gave reference to the `paste special > transpose` option as well in case that helped guide others. The choice of word was also why I had difficulty finding an example online for what I was trying to do.

Comment: No worries :) sorry for the confusion!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

And if you want to try a macro, give this a try:

```
Sub TwoDimension()
    Dim s1 As Worksheet, s2 As Worksheet
    Dim N As Long, i As Long, K As Long
    Dim ii As Long
    Set s1 = Sheets("Sheet1")
    Set s2 = Sheets("Sheet2")
    s1.Range("A1:B1").Copy s2.Range("A1:B1")
    N = s1.Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
    K = 3
    ii = 1
    For i = 2 To N
        If s1.Cells(i, 1) = s1.Cells(i - 1, 1) Then
            s2.Cells(ii, K) = s1.Cells(i, 2)
            K = K + 1
        Else
            ii = ii + 1
            s2.Cells(ii, 1) = s1.Cells(i, 1)
            s2.Cells(ii, 2) = s1.Cells(i, 2)
            K = 3
        End If
    Next i
End Sub
```

The data will be re-formatting on a separate worksheet.

Comment: + 1 Works as expected :)

Comment: I forgot to mention that this will expect the data in column A to be sorted, which is fine by me

Answer (score 2):

I would go with VBA on this one but if you want a non VBA solution then see this. This is something which I came up quickly with and I am sure there could be better formulas to achieve the same thing.

`D2:D6` values can be got from a Pivot on Col A

`E2` has a formula

`=IF(OFFSET(INDIRECT(CELL("address",INDEX($A$2:$A$16,MATCH(D2,$A$2:$A$16,0),1))),0,1)=0,"",OFFSET(INDIRECT(CELL("address",INDEX($A$2:$A$16,MATCH(D2,$A$2:$A$16,0),1))),0,1))`

`F2` has a formula

`=IF(OFFSET(INDIRECT(CELL("address",INDEX($A$2:$A$16,MATCH(D2,$A$2:$A$16,0),1))),1,1)=0,"",OFFSET(INDIRECT(CELL("address",INDEX($A$2:$A$16,MATCH(D2,$A$2:$A$16,0),1))),1,1))`

`G2` has a formula

`=IF(OFFSET(INDIRECT(CELL("address",INDEX($A$2:$A$16,MATCH(D2,$A$2:$A$16,0),1))),2,1)=0,"",OFFSET(INDIRECT(CELL("address",INDEX($A$2:$A$16,MATCH(D2,$A$2:$A$16,0),1))),2,1))`

Now simply copy the formulas down.

[image]

Comment: + 1 also a nice answer when it comes to seeing how it can be done with formulae, I couldn't get it to automatically fill horizontally and I have over 500 for some so VBA seems more appropriate in this case but thank you

Comment: Upvote for sheer balls-to-the-wall insanity and fearlessness in the face of formulae.